# Node.js Dynamodb Issue Using getItem

Tags: node.js

I have written the following code to return a row from a Dynamodb table based on a key called id.

```
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var params = {
    AttributesToGet: [
        "dealername"
    ],
    TableName : "syv_dealer",
    Key : {
        "id" : {
            "S" : "1"
        }
    }
}

db.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err); // an error occurred
    } else {
        console.log(data); // successful response
    }
});
```

My code to write the data to the table worked fine, but the above code keeps generating the following error: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params

The table exists and there is an id attribute with a value of "1" in the table.

I have looked at all the examples I could find and have changed the params statement a hundred times, but nothing has worked. I am sure it is something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because `Key` is an invalid parameter for submitting a request to that API.  Look at the [DynamoDB Query syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) to determine what attributes you can set.

The proper way to perform this query would be with a `KeyConditionExpression` which would look something like:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "syv_dealer",
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :v1",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v1": {"S": "1"}
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "dealername"
}
```

Using `ProjectionExpression` instead of `AttributesToGet` is also the modern way of specifying attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I had changed things so much I hadn't realized I had changed it from a getItem to Query.

The crux of my problem all along was that the function call is asynchronous, so I wasn't being patient and letting the callback execute.

I am new to Node.js, so I am trying to figure out how to check the credentials on a web service call and not have it continue until I have authenticated the requestor. Is there a way on the getItem call to have it be synchronous? I realize I could embed the logic that follows within the getItem callback, but I was really trying to use the same security routine for every endpoint.

Thoughts?